# How can I change the private relay email used in Sign In With Apple?

Tags: ios, login

I am developing an app and implementing Sign In With Apple, logging in/out removing Apple ID and signing in again. I noticed that the relay email is always the same.

Is there a way to reset the relay email?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context on how you define relay mail? This is likely on topic here since you are asking about how Apple services work for developers (which it totally on topic here). The only things we push to stack overflow is code level questions. Like you you would code your back end given an answer here how Apple implemented its service.

Comment: @bmike https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210425#hideemail It's part of Apple's "Sign In With Apple". I don't believe there is a code way of doing this (if at all), which is why I asked on apple.stackexchange.com and not stackoverflow.com. This would be a Apple service feature as I am the user who wants my relay email to be different when I sign out.

Comment: Aah, you want to cycle your “junk” mail alias for a specific app endpoint?

Comment: @bmike Not exactly, the relay is generated by Apple. If I remove the Apple login from appleid.apple.com, I would expect the email to change. It makes testing new sign ins a little complicated, but also the apps can identify the same user (which can be either ideal or unwanted). And I asked this question to find out if anyone knew how to reset the relay email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t change their email addresses short of issuing a new app with a new developer ID. This is documented by Apple.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/communicating_using_the_private_email_relay_service

> Private relay email addresses have the following characteristics:
>
> - They end in @privaterelay.appleid.com.
> - They route emails to one of the Apple ID’s verified email addresses.
> - They’re the same for a user across all apps written by a single development team, and different for the same user across apps written
>   by different development teams.
> - They’re active whether or not the user is signed into a device, and whether or not your app is installed on the device. You may send and
>   receive email to the private email address at any time.
>
> After the user has shared a private relay email address with your app,
> they can find, view, and manage it in their account settings at
> Settings > Apple ID > Password & Security > Apps Using Your Apple ID.

Comment: thanks for asking. This place is amazing IMO and I’m certain others will search for this @MichaelOzeryansky